# ¿Porque tengo este error en vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Lo edite de la siguiente forma, pero aun sigue dandome el error, no tengo mucha experiencia en vue.js, disculpen la molestia. Gracias de antemano

este es el action:

```
getVeterinarios({commit}){
    let veterinarios = []
    db.collection('doctor').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc =>{
            console.log('aqui comienza el error');
            let veterinario = doc.data()
            veterinario.id = doc.id
            veterinarios.push(veterinario)
        })
    })
    commit('setVeterinarios', veterinarios)
},
```

este es el mutation:

```
setVeterinarios(state, veterinarios){

    state.veterinarios = veterinarios

},
```

este es el state:

```
veterinarios: [],
```

Y este es el error que muestra el navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda

Agrego la parte donde llamo a los datos para mostrarlos en pantalla, quizá me este equivocando en algo aquí por eso tengo este error:

Aquí creo el método:

```
methods: {
    getVeterinarios(){

        this.$store.dispatch('doctor/getVeterinarios')
      },
 }
```

Aquí tengo el create:

```
created(){
    this.getVeterinarios()
},
```

Aquí el computed:

```
computed:{
    veterinarios(){
        return this.$store.state.doctor.veterinarios
    },
},
```

el template donde los muestro en la pantalla

```
<template>
                    <vs-tr :data="item" :key="veterinarios.id" v-for="(item, veterinarios) in veterinarios">
                        <!-- v-for="item of veterinarios" :key="item.id
                            :data="tr" :key="indextr" v-for="(tr, indextr) in data-->
                        <vs-td >
                            {{ item.id }}
                        </vs-td>
                        <vs-td>
                            {{ item.apellidos }}
                        </vs-td>
                        <vs-td>
                            {{item.nombres }}
                        </vs-td>
                        <vs-td>
                            {{ item.especialidad }}
                        </vs-td>
                    </vs-tr>
                </template>
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: Carlos, el error es muy claro, no debes mutar directamente el state como lo haces , lo que haces es pasar el Mutation al State, cuando el procedimiento recomendado por vuex es Action -> Mutation y estate, así que si quieres modificar el state tienes que hacer eso .Saludos!

Comment: Cuando declaras variables como const, no puedes modificarlas. Tienes que declararlas como let

Comment: Estas seguro que el error esta aca? no modificas el estado en otro lado? porque este codigo "parece" correcto